# How to chain a fetch API to a function then to another function?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I keep getting syntax error "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: showQuestion is not defined" Trying to find ways to fix this problem. Also I'm still new to the whole thing.

```
fetch(
    'https://jservice.kenzie.academy/api/random-clue?valid=true'
)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(randomDataId => {
        const categoryDataId = randomDataId.categoryId;
        console.log(`category id is: ${categoryDataId}`);

        fetch(
            `https://jservice.kenzie.academy/api/clues?category=${categoryDataId}`
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(randomCatyId => {
                const rightAnswer =
                    randomCatyId.clues[randomData].answer;

                const showTitle =
                    randomCatyId.clues[randomData].category.title;

                const showQuestion =
                    randomCatyId.clues[randomData].question;

                showCategory.innerText = `Category: ${showTitle}`;

                h2Question.innerText = `Question: ${showQuestion}`;

                console.log('question: ' + showQuestion);
                console.log('answer: ' + rightAnswer);

                questionFetch();
            });
    });

function questionFetch() {
    h2Question.innerHTML = `Question: ${showQuestion}`;
}
```

Comment: Tough to tell from the quoted code, but it looks like the reference to showQuestion in the questionFetch function is made outside the scope of definition.

Answer (score 0):

fetch api is async in nature, and you are trying to read the data 'showQuestion' which is not yet available. please see the below code. use async-await, its much better way to play with fetch api.

```
 const randomData = 2; // fake Data

        async function GetDataFromApi(url) {
            const response = await fetch(url);

            return await response.json();
        }


        async function RunApp(params) {

            const randomDataId = await GetDataFromApi('https://jservice.kenzie.academy/api/random-clue?valid=true');

            const categoryDataId = randomDataId.categoryId;
            console.log(`category id is: ${categoryDataId}`);

            const randomCatyId = await GetDataFromApi(`https://jservice.kenzie.academy/api/clues?category=${categoryDataId}`);

            const rightAnswer = randomCatyId.clues[randomData].answer;
            const showTitle = randomCatyId.clues[randomData].category.title;
            const showQuestion = randomCatyId.clues[randomData].question;

            // showCategory.innerText = `Category: ${showTitle}`;

            // h2Question.innerText = `Question: ${showQuestion}`;

            console.log('question: ' + showQuestion);
            console.log('answer: ' + rightAnswer);

            questionFetch(showQuestion);
        }

        function questionFetch(showQuestion) {
            //h2Question.innerHTML = `Question: ${showQuestion}`;
        }

        RunApp();
```

Comment: it worked  thank you! now the only problem is to get the answer portion to not show any errors for the answer function.

Answer (score 0):

The function **questionFetch()** does not have access to the **showQuestion** constant. This is because this constant is defined in the fetch request. The function showQuestion does not have access to data defined inside another function.
(more on 'scope' here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

To fix this, you should supply the constant showQuestion as an argument when calling the function questionFetch:

```
                questionFetch(showQuestion); //we supply the constant to the function
            });
    });

/**
     * function takes an argument, calls it x, and applies it as x. 
     * The name of the argument does not matter, 'x' just the label 
     * this function uses to hold the data supplied 
     * (in our case, the question string);
     * */
function questionFetch(x) { 
    h2Question.innerHTML = `Question: ${x}`;
}
```

Please make sure to define and supply the [**randomData**] argument used in the second fetch function, as it is currently undefined.